# How do you reference the input text from a UIAlertController's Text box?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I have a text box within my alert controller in which the user puts in the what they would like to save the object as. I cannot find a way to reference this string the user puts in.

Answer (score 1):

`UIAlertController` has a [`textFields`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertController/textFields) property which retains an array of `UITextFields` used in your alert controller.

> Use this property to access the text fields displayed by the alert. The text fields are in the order in which you added them to the alert controller. This order also corresponds to the order in which they are displayed in the alert.

If you have only one `UITextField`, you can use `[alertController.textFields firstObject].text` to access the text entered by the user.